# Mysql : Storing large unique tokens as an array in a single column

Tags: mysql

I have to generate unique tokens and store in the database for every client.every day i will be generating 5 millions of unique tokens for all clients.client_id and request_id is used as composite key. for every uniuque client_id and request_id i have to generate 0.5 millions of qr codes.i am storing data in the table as shown below.

```
----------------------------
|client_id|request_id|token|
---------------------------
|1        | 1        | abc |
----------------------------
|1        | 1        | xyz |
----------------------------
|1        | 2        | kbc | 
---------------------------- 
|2        | 1        | def |
----------------------------
|2        | 1        | jkl |
----------------------------
|2        | 2        | des |
----------------------------
```

But the problem with the above structure is that if i have to search all unique tokens(0.5 million) of `client_id` 1 and `request_id` 1 from existing 30 millions records  then it takes more time. sometime searching time is more than a minute. i have already indexed client_id and request_id column but still it is taking time.also sometimes if i run more that 3 select queries then get "mysql server has gone away" error.

I was thinking of storing the unique tokens in a single column in an array so that my searching will be faster with client_id and request_id column.

---

```
|client_id|request_id|token      |
---------------------------------
|1        | 1        | [abc,xyz] |
----------------------------------
|1        | 2        | kbc       |
---------------------------------- 
|2        | 1        | [def,jkl] |
----------------------------------
|2        | 2        | des       |
----------------------------------
```

Please guide me if there is  any drawbacks of using above structure for storing unique tokens for every unique client_id and request_id.

Comment: How are the tokens being used?  One drawback is that a query for a given composite key will always return all tokens.

Comment: forgot to mentioned that sometimes i have to search single unique token from the database also. i think this will be slower. am i right??

Comment: Well the query might be fast, but the app layer might get hosed since it will always get a collection of tokens, all tokens in fact.

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from defining a composite key on `client_id, request_id, token`?

Comment: yes i can do that.. but i am doing mass insertion of 0.5 millions of tokens at a time using single insert into statement. will there be any performance issue if i make these three columns as composite key??